# Как сделать так чтобы в Console Google Cloud, не отключалась консоль?

Tags: консоль, google-cloud

Я хотел загрузить свой проект на Google Cloud Shell, но есть одна проблема. Консоль отключается через время, а мне нужно чтобы когда я закрывал страницу консоль не отключалась.
Как это сделать?